# IOS swift local notification is not working

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, background-task

Below is my code. Basically, I have a weather app. I wanted to Write a swift code, where I will use BGTaskScheduler to schedule a background task every minute.
The background task will set a local notification using UserNotifications.
The task will first call a function named `getWeather` which will return the weather condition.
Set the weather condition as a notification description. And the notification title will be the timestamp. The `registerBackgroundTask()` function is called from AppDelegate after granting notification from `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`. Even if you cannot provide solution, telling me how to debug if the background task is set properly And how to debug if the notification is set properly will help too.

```
    func registerBackgroundTask() {
        let taskIdentifier = "net.tazwar.abohaoa"
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleBackgroundTask(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
        }

        // Schedule the background task to run every minute
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier)
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = false
        request.requiresExternalPower = false

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to schedule background task: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func handleBackgroundTask(task: BGProcessingTask) {
        // Fetch weather condition
        let weatherCondition = getWeather()

        // Create a notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .short)
        content.body = weatherCondition

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "weatherNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Add the notification request to the notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to add notification request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        scheduleNextBackgroundTask()
        task.expirationHandler = {}
    }

    func scheduleNextBackgroundTask() {
        let taskIdentifier = "net.tazwar.abohaoa"
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier)
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = false
        request.requiresExternalPower = false

        // Schedule the background task to run every minute
        let nextFireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
        request.earliestBeginDate = nextFireDate

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to reschedule background task: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func getWeather() -> String {
        return "Sunny"
    }
```

Comment: You can use [this process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting-and-terminating-tasks-during-development) to trigger your background task during development, but it won't run every minute under normal circumstances. You probably also want to use a `BGAppRefreshTask`, not a `BGProcessingTask`. A processing task only runs when the display is off. It is intended for more extensive tasks that need to happen fairly infrequently, such as database grooming.